# Do I need to learn Canvas to learn OpenGL ES in Android Game Development?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-canvas

I'm currently following a book named Beginning Android Games by Zechner and Green and I was wondering if I could skip the part that teaches Canvas and go directly to OpenGL ES ? Is this ok or I'm going to miss some technical stuff that is related to Android?

Comment: Suggestion: never skip any part, but you can read OpenGL ES first, and when you encounter Canvas, you read back the Canvas chapter

Comment: Yes, you can skip it. There is actually not that much in common between the two. The Canvas is another way to draw on the screen (thought, it's really for 2D and it's a much simpler topic than OpenGL, and if you're like most developers, you'll probably just end up skipping the chapter on OpenGL, and come back to the Canvas anyway).